# How to submit a form via ExtJS

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.get('login-openid-form').submit();
```

This isn't working, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ext.get() returns an Ext.Element, not the underlying DOM element.

The underlying element is in a property called .dom.

Try:

```
Ext.get('login-openid-form').dom.submit();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get more Ext-y, you can start to leverage [Ext.form.BasicForm](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.BasicForm):

```
var form = new Ext.form.BasicForm('login-openid-form', { standardSubmit : true });
form.submit();
```

That will expose a more robust form API, which is beyond the scope of this answer, but the docs (linked above) are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail +1